# How to keep certain changed properties unchanged in Realm migration - Swift

Tags: json, swift, realm

When you have a Realm model that looks something like:

```
class Thing: Object, Decodable {
  @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var propertyOne: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var propertyTwo: String? = nil

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "id"
  }
}
```

All of the data is from a JSON file, using a JSON Serializer:

```
func serialize(input sourceName: String) {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sourceName, ofType: nil)
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
        guard json is [AnyObject] else {
            assert(false, "failed to parse")
            return
        }
        do {
            let things = try jsonDecoder.decode([Thing].self, from: data)
            let realm = try! Realm()
            for thing in things {
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(thing)
                    // realm.add(thing, update: .modified) wipes out all changes
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("failed to convert data: \(error)")
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

`propertyOne`'s info is gotten from the JSON. `propertyTwo`'s value is meant to be inputted from within the app. Once I serialize the JSON again, all changes to `propertyTwo` are wiped out. How do I make a migration without restoring it to the original JSON file? I want to keep some properties unchanged during a migration/new serialization.

In my AppDelegate, this is my code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let serializer = JSONSerializer()
serializer.serialize(input: "Nafliah.json")
```

This works if I have `realm.add(thing, update: .modified)` in my serializer. But this wipes out all changes made within the app. If I change it to this:

```
if save.bool(forKey: "serilized") == false {
    let serializer = JSONSerializer()
    serializer.serialize(input: "Nafliah.json")
    save.set(true, forKey: "serilized")
}
```

And make the serializer part `realm.add(thing)`, it works and does not wipe out changed data every time the app is opened.

The issue is, once I add a new object to the JSON file, it obviously does not get added to the realm. I must serialize the JSON again. This, however, deletes all changes done in the 2 properties that are only meant to be changed by the user in the app.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. *How do I make a migration without restoring it to the original JSON file* - do you mean a Realm Migration from one version to the next? This `realm.add(thing, update: .modified)` will update an existing object with new data for fields that were modified or add an object. It won't delete data. Most importantly, **it only works for objects that have a primary key**, your realm objects (which are not realm objects) do not have a primary key. See [Primary Keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#objects-with-primary-keys)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Basically, I have a JSON file will thousands of objects. Using the JSON serializer, I turn them into Realm objects. Each object has like 8 properties. 6 of them are set by the JSON file, 2 of them are nil, but are written to in the app. When t this change happens, the JSON file obviously does not change, only the Realm object. Using my current model, if I wanted to add one more object later on or add another property, the next time I serialize the JSON, everything is restored to exactly how the JSON is, removing all changes made within the app.

Comment: How do I make it where only the 6 properties are changed, which are set in the JSON file. I don't want the changes made in the app, that are not in the JSON, to be deleted. Using `realm.add(thing, update: .modified)` or `realm.add(thing)` deleted changes made within the app—not shown in the JSON.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You're asking about a Realm Migration - adding another Realm object is unrelated to migrations. But adding a property IS related. However, the next time you serialize your JSON would be an independent function from the migration so the migration code may be where the issue is. That being said, maybe when your serializing again, your overwriting existing objects or setting the user entered data to nil. Probably need to expand the question a bit. Also, is this a local realm or a full/partial cloud realm?

Comment: It's a local realm. I fixed the question to explain further.

Comment: Wait. I just re-read this *Once I serialize the JSON again, all changes to propertyTwo are wiped out*. That's correct behavior; *propertyTwo* is not a managed Realm object and that property will not be stored in Realm so it would be 'wiped out' every time the app is opened. It's purely an in-memory var that is only alive within the function or class while it's in-scope. One the app quits or the function going out fo scope, that variable is gone (nil).

Comment: @Jay I figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to do a partial serialization.

Changed this:

```
realm.add(thing, update: .modified)
```

To:

```
realm.create(Thing.self, value: [
   "id": thing.id,
   "propertyOne": thing.propertyOne
   // Leave out propertyTwo to leave it unchanged
], update: .modified)
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out but for clarity, the first line isn't valid as it's trying to add a *class* to realm instead of an *object*. See the API for [realm.add](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Structs/Realm.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0V3add_6updateyAA6ObjectC_AC12UpdatePolicyOtF) and note the first parameter is an object, not a class. "Adds an unmanaged *object* to this Realm."

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link for Migrating Realm for existing properties

https://docs.realm.io/sync/v/3.x/using-synced-realms/migrating-your-data

Comment: The OP is asking about a local Realm so those docs do not apply - they are for sync'd realms.